# Natural numbers defined as cardinals of finite sets?

Tags: set-theory, natural-numbers

I am interesting on the formal construction of $\mathbb{N}$. Obviously, I am familiarized with Peano axioms. I am looking for another constructions. For example, using Zermelo-fraenkel axioms, one can construct $\mathbb{N}$ as the intersection of all the inductive subsets of an inductive subset (which exits by virtue of the axiom of infinity). My question is if this could be another way to construct natural numbers.

1. Define equipotence relation over the class of all sets.
2. Define finite sets.
3. The axiom of cardinality says that for each set A there exists a unique cardinal $a$ such that $a$ is equipotent to A.
4. Define $\mathbb{N}$ as the set L of all finite cardinal numbers (note that a cardinal is a set and we know when a set is finite or not).

Is this a correct way to define natural numbers? **How can be shown that L is indeed a set?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you defining "cardinal"?

Comment: I assume a cardinal is simply a special ordinal. The smallest infinite ordinal is a set and contains all finite ordinals

Comment: I am following the definition of the book 'A book of set theory' by Charles Pinter. See chapter 8, axiom of cardinality.

Comment: Peano arithmetic is *not* a way to construct natural numbers; it *axiomatizes* what natural numbers are.

Comment: In a now-deleted comment, you mentioned that you define "finite" as "not in bijection with a proper subset of itself." This notion, called "Dedekind finiteness," **isn't** equivalent to actual finiteness (= "is in bijection with some ordinal $<\omega$") in set theory without the axiom of choice: it's consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ *(= usual axioms of set theory except choice)* that there are infinite sets which are Dedekind finite. To get true finiteness you either need to assume choice or work via an explicit numbering - which is basically just building $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: There are definitions of finiteness that don't require choice or reference the natural numbers, though... the one I always remember is 'having an ordering that is both a well-ordering and a reverse-well-ordering''... [here is a list.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set#Necessary_and_sufficient_conditions_for_finiteness)

Comment: Thanks both Noah and spaceisdarkgreen. Your comments solve my doubt and even include some interestering information. I did not know Dedekind finiteness wasn't equivalent to actual definition of finiteness... so I guess the only logical order is to construct $\mathbb{N}$ (as the intersection of all inductive subsets of an inductive set) and then we can talk properly of cardinality and finite and infinite sets.